# CakePHP application on a hosted server?

Tags: cakephp, web-hosting

How do I run [cakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) application on a hosted server?

I have created my own application in CakePHP. It was running fine locally. But when I upload it to server, it's gives a 404 Not Found Error.

Can anybody tell me how to upload CakePHP to the hosted server?

Answer (score 6):

I answered a similar question on serverfault.
Here's the link: [CakePHP Hosting](https://serverfault.com/questions/66860/setting-up-cake-on-hostgator/71056#71056/)

Here's another link from the Bakery:
[Installing CakePHP on shared hosting](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/installing-cakephp-on-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 0):

Tip:  Make  tmp, cache   mod 777

delete the cache files from the folders inside cache..